# How can I insertion sort an ArrayList<String> Alphabetically?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

First off, I will say that this is homework, and I would like help rather than straight out answers. Because it is homework and not a real application, I am limited to the following classes:

```
java.util.ArrayList
java.util.Scanner
```

For my AP Computer Science class, I on creating a program that will accept names via `System.in` and input them into an `ArrayList<String>` where they will then be sorted in alphabetical order. 
I have done everything, but my insertion sort only seems to sort names by first letter, rather than by complete alphabetical-ness.

The following is my current insertion sorting method.

```
public static ArrayList<String> doInsertionSort(ArrayList<String> a) { //helper method that performs an insertion sort upon an ArrayList<String>.

      String temp; //temporary string for holding data.

      for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) { //One major sweep occurs, with sorting pulses working backwards.
                                          //NOTE:Starts at position 1 of ArrayList<String> so that j-1 doesn't throw OutOfBounds exception.
                                          //Besides, there would be nothing to swap position 0 of ArrayList<String> in this particular inserton sort.

          for(int j = i; j > 0; j--) {  //starts at position i in ArrayList<String> and works backwards.

              if(a.get(j).charAt(0) < a.get(j - 1).charAt(0)) {  //if the String at position j is less than the string behind it, 
                                                                 //swap the two. This keeps happening until position 0 is reached.
                  temp = a.get(j);
                  a.set(j, a.get(j-1));
                  a.set(j-1, temp);
              }
          }
      }
      return a;
  }   //end doInsertionSort
```

I tested my sorting algorithm with the following data:

```
z
Mariah
Carrie
cHaRlOtTe
caRl
joSe
johnathan

[Carrie, Charlotte, Carl, Jose, Johnathan, Mariah, Z]
```

was my output, when it should have been

```
[Carl, Carrie, Charlotte, Johnathan, Jose, Mariah, Z]
```

I got 100% on the assignment (we "learn" from an online java course, which comes with a handy dandy submission that evaluates source code) but I am unsatisfied with my results, as I didn't manage to get a perfect alphabetical sort.

I'm just not quite sure how to tell java how to sort completely alphabetically.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: Many people have pointed out that `String` contains a method `compareTo()` which was exactly what I was looking for, although I am unsure who to give the best answer to.

Comment: `a.get(j).charAt(0) < a.get(j - 1).charAt(0)` <= why are you comparing only the first characters of each string?

Comment: @dhke I'm sorry, I forgot that String had such a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is `String.compareTo()` function which compare strings alphabetically.

`a.compareTo(b)` return `0` if strings are equal, returns `1` if `a > b` alphabeticaly, otherwise it returns `-1`.

So you can just remove your inner loop which iterates threw strings and compare their chars, using charAt, by comparing string using compartTo.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that String had the compareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

use `compareTo()` method to compare `String`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

You can also use `Collections.sort(list)`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the line of code you need to look at is :

```
if(a.get(j).charAt(0) < a.get(j - 1).charAt(0))
```

Think about what this is comparing a.get(j) is a string and a.get(j-1) is a string so what is the last part doing?